# Datepicker & autocomplete after replaceWith() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, datepicker, replacewith

I'm facing a dumb issue between datepicker/autocomplete and replacewith(). I've a form in which the users can add several rows and remove them as well. To make such thing, I've set a cloning. Once the cloning is made, I do a replaceWith() in order to change the names of the inputs as the attr function makes silly things with IE by replacing name by SubmitName.

The replacewith works fine but the datepicker function or autocomplete function doesn't work anymore. FYI, this block is right after the HTML Form. I've try it on several ways as show below but none works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uniqueLeg = 1;
$('.addLeg').click(function() {
    var copy = $('#Leg').clone(true,true);
    var formId = 'Leg' + window.uniqueLeg;
    copy.attr('id', formId );
    copy.removeAttr('style');

    copy.find(':input#tripdate').each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='tripdate" + window.uniqueLeg + "' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniqueLeg + "' class='datepicker' />");
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
$('#trip').append(copy);
window.uniqueLeg++;
});
```

or

```
    copy.find(':input#tripdate').each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='tripdate" + window.uniqueLeg + "' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniqueLeg + "' class='datepicker' />");
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
```

or

```
    copy.find(':input#tripdate').each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='tripdate" + window.uniqueLeg + "' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniqueLeg + "' class='datepicker' />");
        $('tripdate'+window.uniqueLeg).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
```

none works. The jquery-ui is declared on the top of the page

```
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <TITLE> Dev page </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="src/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="src/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
            $( ".aptsearch" ).autocomplete({source:'suggest_apt.php', minLength:3});
            $( ".actsearch" ).autocomplete({
                source:'suggest_act.php', 
                minLength:3,
                select: function (event, ui) { 
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    loadAC(ui.item.value, id); 
                }
            });
        });...
```

Besides that, even the addClass or RemoveClass function doesn't seems to work. Please advise, I can't see what is missing.
Suggestions are welcome.

html structure before news rows

```
<INPUT id=tripdate0 class="datepicker hasDatepicker" name=tripdate0 jQuery191007588717778684739="15">
```

after news rows

```
<INPUT id=tripdate1 class=datepicker name=tripdate1>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in the console ? one more thing, why are u making multiple calls to `.datepicker()`, since you need it for all the  newly added rows, you can call it once within `$(document).ready()`. if possible can you post the html structure after the new rows are added

Comment: I don't get any errors but autocomplete and datepicker don't work on the newly rows added. 
In regards of $(document).ready(function){ it doesn't replace the fact that .datepicker() has to be called again after a cloning. I just tried and it didn't worked without it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find out what was the issue. The AddClass and .datepicker can't work on a function where the input id has been changed by the replacewith.
The only way to fix this was to add an additionnal function afterwards which selects the new modified input and add's the class datepicker + initialize .datepicker()

Looks a bit dirty but works at least. If you do have some suggestions to improve this, please feel free to share it :)

```
    copy.find(':input#tripdate'+window.uniqueLeg).each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('datepicker');
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
```